# How can I convert this curl call to XML Http Request call?

Tags: javascript, curl, xmlhttprequest, request-headers

**I have something like this** :

> ```
> curl "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token" \
>      -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
>      -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}"
> ```

I want to convert it xhr object in Javascript. Can you help me ? I
mean ;

```
xhr.open(....) 
xhr.setRequestHeader(.....) 
xhr.send(.....)
```

Comment: I recommend you don't. :-) Instead, use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch). Just beware of the footgun in the API I describe [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Can I use Jquery instead of fetch?

Comment: You can, but I can't see any reason to.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you don't. :-) Instead, use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch), the newer standard replacement for `XMLHttpRequest`. Just beware of the footgun in the API I describe [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html). To see how, let's look at what that `curl` call is doing:

- `-H` defines a header.
- `-d` specifies data that `curl`...

  > ...sends...in a POST request to the HTTP server, in the same way that a browser does when a user has
  > filled in an HTML form and presses the submit button. This will cause curl to pass the data to the server using  the  con‐
  > tent-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

So looking at the `fetch` ways you do that:

- Headers are defined via the `headers` object in the request initializer.
- Data is sent via the `body` property of the request initializer.
- You specify a POST request via the `method` property in the request initializer.
- To send data compatible with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, the easiest thing is to use a [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) object.

So that gives us:

```
fetch("https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    body: new URLSearchParams([
        ["grant_type", "client_credentials"],
        ["client_id", client_id],            // I'm assuming you have this in a variable
        ["client_secret", client_secret],    // Same assumption
    ]),
})
.then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
    }
    // ...if relevant, read the response via `json` or `text` or others;
    // here I'll use `text` AS AN EXAMPLE
    return response.text();
})
.then(data => {
    // ...use the data...
})
.catch(error => {
    // ...handle/report error...
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It's working now, I can fetch the data